# no access to result of downloadUrl in Firebase Storage emulator

Tags: android, firebase-storage, firebase-tools

I try to test my app with the Firebase Emulator Suite, especially I'm using the Storage emulator.

Now I try to get access to a successfully uploaded image via the `downloadURL` method and passing them into a `FileInputStream`. Unfortunately I get an `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

I think the reason is, because the resulting URL from `downloadURL`started with `http:/10.0.2.2:9199` instead of `http:/localhost:9199`. Substitute `10.0.2.2`with `localhost`and pasting the URL in a browser shows the image.

Here are my code snippets:

```
Firebase.storage.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9199)
...
val imageKey = getNewImageStorageKey()!!+".jpg"
val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bitmapToUpload.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)

mStorageProductImageReference.child(imageKey).putBytes(outputStream.toByteArray()).await()
var imageURL = mStorageProductImageReference.child(imageKey).downloadUrl.await()
val inputStream = FileInputStream(imageURL.toString())
```

This leads to following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/10.0.2.2:9199/v0/b/myapp-e02f1.appspot.com/o/product_images%2F-aQD1EpITebrYZnMtKOq.jpg?alt=media&token=97f3bc03-4f23-4b95-a8a0-70245bfbae91

The Storage emulator is running on:

```
│ Storage        │ localhost:9199                   │ http://localhost:4000/storage
```

I'm an a MacOS system if this is relevant.

Any suggestions on how to use the result from `downloadURL` to get access to the uploaded image in the Firebase Storage emulator?

Answer (score 2):

I'm so damn st....

While hitting the post button, the resolution came into my mind.

I can not use a `FileInputStream` for a http request. Sorry for that.

With a simple:

```
val connection = URL(imageURL.toString()).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
val resultBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.inputStream)
```

I could confirm that uploading and downloading is working.